# Omnipay Stripe Extra Parameters

Tags: stripe-payments, omnipay

Im trying to use the Omnipay API with Stripe, but I can't pass in extra parameters such as "Name", "Metadata", or "Zip".

```
   // The token is grabbed from stripe JS
   $this->stripe_gateway = Omnipay::create('Stripe');

   $response = $this->stripe_gateway->purchase([
        'amount' => $amount,
        'currency' => 'usd',
        'name' => $name,
        'description' => $product->title,
        'zip_address' => $zip,
        'metadata' => [
            'name' => $name,
            'user_id' => $this->session->get('id')
        ],
        'token' => $stripeToken,
    ])->send();
```

I cant get anything to work, is this not built into the API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Omnipay uses it's own parameter names, not Stripe's. That's because Omnipay tries to abstract most of the differences between the various payment gateways.

Right now, the `omnipay/stripe` package doesn't support sending some of those parameters (only `amount`, `currency`, `description`, and now `metadata`). You can see the supported parameters here:

https://github.com/omnipay/stripe/blob/master/src/Message/AuthorizeRequest.php

That said, you can still easily access the underlying Stripe request to add your own custom parameters:

```
$request = $this->stripe_gateway->purchase([
    'amount' => $amount,
    'token' => $stripeToken,
    'metadata' => ['foo' => 'bar'],
]);
$data = $request->getData();

$data['zip_address'] = '12345';
$data['another_custom_parameter'] = 'wow';
$response = $request->sendData($data);
```

Note that:

```
$data = $request->getData();
$response = $request->sendData($data);
```

is exactly the same as calling:

```
$response = $request->send();
```

Alternatively, you could create a pull request to add extra parameters to the Omnipay Stripe package. I just added the `metadata` parameter as an example of this:

https://github.com/omnipay/stripe/commit/99c82dc42c7c0b9ec58d8c4fb917f3dc5d1c23e2